# What can we do to advertise to Asia devs about this site?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

It's pretty clear that we get a steady stream of questions when Europe/Africa and the Americas are on-line, but so far we seem to get very few questions during the Asia working day. I can't believe that they don't also have questions.

(Is it possible that stack exchange is blocked by the great firewall of China?)

Comment: Seems like `ajax.googleapis.com` is blocked there so in China they get a degraded experience but should still be fairly usable. So question is still how do we get engagement from that community?

Comment: We do have a large Substrate community in Asia/Pacific.. Agree with you that we should find a way to welcome them here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think we should be doing anything specific to the Asian community that we wouldn't do for the global community.

Most asian specific efforts I have seen usually involves localization, but as mentioned before, StackExchange is an English only site.

The only thing I can think of is to use any asia specific sites to also advertise the existence of this community.